# Appending relativePath to formData for each file in folder

Tags: jquery-file-upload

I'm using Jquery-File-Upload(https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) for whole folder upload. 
And I'm having problem in uploading file with **appended relativePath** to *formData* object. Below is a code:

```
var formData = $( ":input" ).serializeArray();
  $('#upload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
      console.log('Added file: ' + file.name+ ' Path :'+file.relativePath);
      data.formData = {'relativePath': file.relativePath};
    });
     console.log(data);
  });
```

I'm unable to get 'relativePath' parameter  on server side for each individual file. I'm passing this parameter to preserve directory structure on server.

Comment: You are only setting a property for the `data` object itself, overwriting it each time – without any connection to the individual files.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for replay. But the Documentation suggests the similar way I did (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data#adding-additional-form-data-programmatically).

Comment: That might be, but there’s no each involved, they are doing it only for a single file upload there if I’m not mistaken …